# How do I get the rotation angle for a google street view hyperlink?

Tags: c#, html, google-maps, silverlight, hyperlink

I have an application where users can look up different addresses. I want to be able to provide a link to the street view, but I have no way of knowing the rotation angle for each and every address.

I have found other threads on how to create a google street view link and what all of the parameters are. However, I cannot find anything on how to automatically get the rotation angle, so that the camera is facing the right way.

When I link to google maps with just the address, I can simply click on street view and it somehow points at the address without me needing to provide a rotation angle.

I actually have center points for all of the addresses, but I don't have a position for the google street view car, so I can't determine which direction for the camera to face.

This is a Silverlight application in C#, but I was planning on just using a hyperlink.

How can I create a google street view link without knowing the rotation angle?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/) page.

Notice, in the Optional Parameters section, it includes the default values for those optional parameters, if you dont specify the values, it will use the default ones.

Those default ones might not give you the view you want, so you might try different values.

Note, even you know the angle/position of the google street view car, you still cant determine which direction is the "best" for you.